Sending emails without custom DNS validation
We are moving the infrastructure over for our corporate client system to AWS; however at the moment, we send emails through sendmail on our servers, and only have an SPF record with each client set up.
I understand you can no longer send an email through sendmail on EC2 servers, and I don't want to have to set up an identity for each domain when using SES if I can avoid it, as there are loads of them, and I will need each clients IT department to set it up.
What alternatives are there? I have looked by can't find a 3rd party to use that would allow set up with just an SPF record.
Any help with how this should be set up please let me know, ideally we would continue to use mail within our PHP send script.
Any 3rd party integration would need to be one we can connect to through PHP.

You'd probably get more help with this on a system admin-focused site such as serverfault. It doesn't appear to be a directly programming-related issue

P.S. Any 3rd party integration would need to be one we can connect to through PHP...well php, as a full-featured langage, can send any message anywhere using pretty much any protocol. And for the well-known email ones such as SMTP, IMAP or POP there are ready-made libraries and functions in PHP. Or if the service ends up using a HTTP API in front of the email service, PHP can obviously talk to that very easily as well. So I wouldn't let that bit of it worry you particularly.

And ideally we would continue to use mail within our PHP send script...well if that's your requirement then you don't really need to worry about PHP at all, you'd just have to ensure that the local MTA can connect to the 3rd party. If it can't/won't be configured to do that, then you can reconsider what you do in the PHP code. You said that sendmail no longer works on EC2, but that's what PHP's mail() relies on, so I suspect you aren't going to be able to stick to this requirement.

"I understand you can no longer send an email through sendmail on EC2 servers"   EC2 instances are the same as any other virtual machine.  All the same considerations apply.  Alternately, you can use SES with SMTP so you don't need to configure each PHP server to be an acceptable mail server.  Or your own centralized mail server.

@erik258 - no you can't send a mail from a server on an EC2 instance, this has been closed off by AWS.

@ADyson

I will try serverfault. I rarely need to do anything like this, so its a bit new to me.


@ADyson - I said Ideally, its not a requirement, the main thing is to send emails without having to get clients to update DNS records. Its a pain with massive companies.
For clarity though mail() does not rely on sendmail, it uses what ever its been. configured to use, eg exim etc

@AKT ok perhaps I should have said it uses sendmail by default. So are you saying amazon have closed all ways to send mail from ec2 machines? Don't you get full control of the machine to do as you please with it?

@AKT I'm not familiar with any such restriction.  In fact I operate a mail server on an EC2 instance that can still send email successfully.  I just tested it and gmail received it fine.  Do you have some reason to believe so?  Not that I'd recommend running your own MTA - too hard to get emails accepted these days.  But AWS isn't doing anything to stop you.

Your organization has two choices: continue routing mail through whatever infrastructure already matches the DNS records; or update the DNS records to allow new source(s) of the mail.  But I agree, you should make this as small and permanent a change as possible.  That's the big reason that literally sending from the individual servers is not what you want.  Look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-smtp.html you can pretty easily send through SES for your domain with a few changes to your DNS records.

@erik258 AWS have closed port 25 (and the other mail based ports) by default on all EC2 servers, meaning you have to connect to SES to send emails.
Are you using linux? and just sendmail to send?

Lol, it's been so long I've forgotten having to go through this : https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle Or perhaps it's new since I set it up.  So by default it's blocked, but they will open it if you ask.  To answer your question, yes it's linux and not sendmail but postfix.

Ahh haa - I did not know this was even an option. I will get on it thank you!
